# How to stop Git for Windows terminal closing after execution from android studio

Tags: windows, git, android-studio, sh

I am running latest android studio on a windows 10 pc
I have git for windows ver 2.22.0.windows.1
From within android studios terminal I am trying to run a shell script called graphhopper.sh as per https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md#maps
The problem is it closes immediately upon execution and I cant see whats going on, 
I've added 'pause' into the script but this command is not recognised.
How do I stop it closing

Comment: change `pause` to  `read`. Press Enter Key to continue, or `Ctrl-C` to stop execution then. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend giving the executable (if trustful) admin permission to be performed. This might help with the whole 'closing' problem. If not, I would then try making sure you have the correct [specific documentation](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/windows-setup.md) for graphhopper. As a last resort I would head towards the graphhopper forums or [here](https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/graphhopper-sh-does-not-resolve-maven/4273) (This question, for the most part, is completely answered on the graphhopper forums.